# How does $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-m+1) \cdot \frac{(n-m)(n-m-1)\cdots1}{(n-m)(n-m-1)\cdots1} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots1}{(n-m)(n-m-1)\cdots1} $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having issues understanding how the previous line goes to the net line.

$$
\text{Assume } m \le n \\
n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-m+1) \cdot \frac{(n-m)(n-m-1)\cdots1}{(n-m)(n-m-1)\cdots1} \\
= \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots1}{(n-m)(n-m-1)\cdots1} $$

I just don't see how the numerator of the fraction in first line cancels out yet nothing in the denominator cancels out.

Also I'm not sure what tag this question should go under.

Comment: They don't cancel you just have that the first product is from $n$ to $n-m+1$ and second is from $n-m$ to $1$ combining them together you have that it is the product from $n$ to $1$

Comment: Thank you. Also should I delete this or can I close the question?

Comment: If you substitute in some specific values, say $n=7$ and $m=4$, I think you will understand what is happening.

Comment: $A\cdot \dfrac{B}{B} = \dfrac{AB}{B}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at a concrete example, say $n=6$ and $m=3$. Then $n-m+1=6-3+1=4$, so we have

$$\begin{align*}
6\cdot5\cdot4&=6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot\color{brown}1\\\\
&=6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot\color{brown}{\frac{3\cdot2\cdot1}{3\cdot2\cdot1}}\\\\
&=\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot\color{brown}{3\cdot2\cdot1}}{\color{brown}{3\cdot2\cdot1}}\\\\
&=\frac{6!}{3!}\;.
\end{align*}$$

The general case is the same thing.

Comment: How did you colour the text?

Comment: @user1766555: Right click on the formula --> "Show Math as" --> "TeX Commands".